# Core Plot Graph Capture as an Image

Tags: ios, core-plot

Is there a way to capture the Core Plot Line Graph as an image as a whole.Currently I have scrolling enabled in the horizontal direction and when I use the imageOfLayer method provided; it gives only the on-screen content.I want to capture the whole graph including the offscreen content as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, what you see is what you get. You don't have to display the graph on screen to draw it however. You can make a graph offscreen, size it however you want, and render it to an image without ever displaying it on screen.

Comment: So like don't add the graph to the hosting view and keep the bounds of the graph of the size we want the image to be rendered..Right??

Comment: Yes. That’s how you do it.